# Faces of a Planar Graph

Tags: graph-theory

It is given that in a planar graph an edge $e$ does not lie on a cycle. Then $e$ lies on the boundary of exactly one face. How this can be showed?

Comment: how do you define a face ?

Comment: faces are the connected components of the complement of the graph

Answer (score 2):

First we assume that the graph $G$ is finite, since it is possible to disconnect $\mathbb R^2$ by an infinite graph not containing any cycle (a line).

We show that if $e$ lies on the boundary of more than one face it must lie on a cycle:

First it is clear that in this case $e$ lies on the boundary of precisely two faces $F_1$ and $F_2$.
Observe that either $F_1$ or $F_2$ is bounded since otherwise $G$ would be infinite as there would be points of $G$ of arbitrary distance to $(0,0)$. Thus we may assume that $F_2$ is bounded. Let $c = \partial \overline F_2$ denote the boundary of the closure of $F_2$. Then $c$ is a cycle in $G$. Since we have $e \subset \overline F_2$, $e \subset \overline F_1$ and $F_1 \cap F_2 = \emptyset$ it follows that $e \subset \partial \overline F_2 = c$ and we are done.

Comment: 1. Here you have deduced that the boundary of a bounded face is a cycle....this is not true in general...since there may be edges that lies inside the cycle and hence boundary of the face contained in that cycle...that problem can't be removed by this argument

Comment: You are right, the boundary of a bounded face itself may not be a cycle. But each point of the boundary of a bounded face lies on some cycle, this is enough.